# How to prevent Bootbox from displaying twice after a double click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I have a  `<ul>` element that opens a bootbox when it's clicked. Double clicking this element triggers the onclick in JQuery twice

```
$("#email-list").on("click", ".list-group-item", function (e) {
bootbox.confirm("Send a forgotten password email to " + email + "?", function (result) {...}}
```

I tried using 'e.preventDefault()'

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#email-list").dblclick(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I even tried disabling clicking on the element but both failed. The bootbox still appears twice.

```
$("#email-list").bind('click', function () { return false; });
//...do stuff
$("#email-list").unbind('click');
```

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: can you give `#email-list`, or the bootbox a new class like `.open` when you click? then check if that element has the class open, if not, do what it needs to do

Comment: Show how you retrieve bootbox and what you have try to prevent it to appear twice.

Comment: you want it to work with singe click as well as with double click?

Comment: If you want to bind an handler only to a double click event, use `.on( "dblclick", selector, handler )` or its shortcut `.dblclick(...)` However, I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.

Comment: I have added a few details. @dfsq yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another solution can be to add:

```
bootbox.hideAll();
```

to hide any other bootboxes right before showing the bootbox like so:

```
bootbox.hideAll();
bootbox.confirm("Some Message " , function (result){/*do stuff*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#email-list").on("click", ".list-group-item", function (e) {
   if(!$('#myModal').is(':visible')){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');  
   }
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I did, `$('#myModal').is(':visible')` is always false, hence it's always displaying the bootbox

Answer (score 0):

Use the click event, then you can replace

```
e.preventDefault();
```

with

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

or

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured the best way to do this is to separate the two events; onclick and dbclick, I used something like this, I hope it will save someone some time:

```
var DELAY = 700, clicks = 0, timer = null;

    $(function () {

        $("#email-list").on("click", ".list-group-item", function (e) {

            clicks++;  //count clicks

            if (clicks == 1) {
                   //do stuff
                    clicks = 0;  //after action performed, reset counter

                }, DELAY);
            } else {

                clearTimeout(timer);    //prevent single-click action
                clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
                return false;
            }

        })
        .on("dblclick", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();  //cancel system double-click event
        });
   }
```